# Check if page on d0xbin exists?

Tags: java, http, url

I've been afraid for some time that I might be doxxed. For this reason I want to write an automation in Java to not have to manually search all possible keywords every day. However, I always get a 200 response code due to DDoS Protection. Is there any way to get around this?

Here's my Code:

```java
URL u = new URL ( "https://doxbin.org/upload/afafgFsg/");
        HttpURLConnection huc =  (HttpURLConnection)  u.openConnection ();
        huc.setRequestMethod ("GET");  //OR  huc.setRequestMethod ("HEAD");
        huc.connect () ;
        int code = huc.getResponseCode() ;
        System.out.println(code);
        if (code == 200) {
            System.out.println("Success");
        } else if (code == 404) {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
```

The link is currently still provisional. I just want to get the system working once.

I have tried every conceivable method so far, but every time it fails due to DDoS protection.

Comment: You can try setting a valid user agent in the request header. Maybe it thinks you're a bot because you don't set one. I would aim to replicate all the headers that Chrome sends.

Comment: The problem is that I now get a 503 Service Unavailable Error.

Here are my Headers:
https://prnt.sc/Jb8A1-msfmQd